# ¿Como filtro en Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, linq, netcore

Tengo 4 entidades: Paises, Estados, Municipios y Colonias

```
public class Paises 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Nombre { get; set; }
   public List<Estados> Estados { get; set; }
}

public class Estados 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Nombre { get; set; }
   public int PaisesId { get; set; }
   public Paises Paises { get; set; }
   public List<Municipios> Municipios { get; set; }
}

public class Municipios 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Nombre { get; set; }
   public int EstadosId { get; set; }
   public Estados Estados { get; set; }
   public List<Colonias> Colonias { get; set; }
}

public class Colonias 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Nombre { get; set; }
   public string CodigoPostal { get; set; }
   public int MunicipiosId { get; set; }
   public Municipios Municipios { get; set; }
}
```

Estoy haciendo una endpoint, el cual recibe como parametro el CodigoPostal, entonces debo mostrar el pais (objeto), estado (objeto), municipio (objeto) y colonias (lista) de ese codigo postal.

El resultado que quiero es el siguiente:

```
Pais      -> Id: 1, Nombre: México 
Estado    -> Id: 1, Nombre: Veracruz
Municipio -> Id: 1, Nombre: Veracruz
Colonias  -> Id: 1, Nombre: Rio medio, CodigoPostal: 91808
             Id: 2, Nombre: Oasis, CodigoPostal: 91808
             Id: 3, Nombre: Brisas, CodigoPostal: 91808
             ....
```

He investigado y dentro del "where" se ponen los filtros y por cada entidad hija se agrega un Select

```
var query = await context.Paises.Include(x => x.Estados)
                                   .ThenInclude(x => x.Municipios).ThenInclude(x => x.Colonias)
                                .Where(x => x.Estados.Select(x => x.Municipios.Select(x => x.Colonias.Select(x => x.CodigoPostal).Contains(CodigoPostal))))
                                .ToListAsync();
```

Pero me lanza el siguiente error:

```
Error CS0029: No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<bool>>' en 'bool'
```

¿Que me falta hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atendiendo a tu diseño de clases te propongo la siguiente consulta:

```
Var lista = (from p in context.Paises
              from e in p.Estados
               from m in e.Municipios
             select new
             {
                 País = p.NombrePais,
                 Estado = e.NombreEstado,
                 Municipio = m.NombreMunicipio,
                 Colonias = m.Colonias.Where(c => c.CodigoPostal == cp)
            }).Where(l => l.Colonias.Any()).ToList();
```

Se hacen tres **from anidados**, el **from** más externo recorrerá los países, el segundo **from** recorrerá los estados de cada país, y el tercer **from** recorrerá los municipios de cada estado. En la **cláusula select** se construye un **objeto anónimo** con las propiedades que deseas: El país, el estado, el municipio y las colonias dentro de ese municipio cuyo código postal se corresponde con el que deseas comparar. Posteriormente se utiliza el **método extensor Where** para obtener solamente los elementos de la anterior consulta que tienen al menos una colonia, es decir se selecciona un país, que a su vez tiene un estado, donde ese estado tiene a su vez un municipio, donde ese municipio tiene al menos una colonia cuyo código postal sea igual al indicado.

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

**Nota**: Tú problema puede resolverse de muchas formas, yo te propongo esta solución, analizala y adáptala a tus necesidades.

Comment: Muchas gracias, tomé como base tu respuesta para resolver mi problema

Answer (score 2):

El argumento de un `where` es una función que retorna `true/false`, tu tienes un `select` que es una función que retorna un `IEnumerable<T>`

En Linq con las propiedades de Navegación puedes comenzar a buscar desde cualquier extremo, en tu caso yo comenzaría desde `Municipios`

Algo así:

```
var Municipios = context.Municipios
                    .Include(x => x.Colonias)
                    .Include(x => x.Estados)
                        .ThenInclude(x => x.Paises);

var query = from a in Municipios
            let Colonias = a.Colonias.Where(x=>x.CodigoPostal == CodigoPostal)
            where Colonias.Any()
            select new
            {
                Pais = new { a.Estados.Paises.Id, a.Estados.Paises.Nombre },
                Estado = new { a.Estados.Id, a.Estados.Nombre },
                Municipio = new { a.Id, a.Nombre },
                Colonias
            };
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu lógica me servirá para otros temas